# Convert an object to string type for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, string-comparison

I am reading a csv file and writing its contents to a dataframe.

```
         df1 = pd.read_csv(r'/C:/Data.csv', sep=',',  names=["a", "b", "c"])
```

I am later comparing the data in one column to a column in a different dataframe.
The code fails to execute showing the error '('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')'.

The have tried using astype method in different variations and nothing has worked so far.
Pasting below a piece of code that I have tried that also did not work.

```
if (df3[df3['c'] == 'Science']):
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me understand the problem to get it resolved. Thanks in advance.

Adding the code below for better understanding...

```
df1 = --reading from local(id, student name, class columns)
df2 = --creating this to save the output from the json method(id, subject, marks)
url = --endpoint 

def passfail_logic(row):
  if ((df3['subject'] == 'viva' & df3['marks'] > 85 ) & (df3['subject'] == 'science' & df3['marks'] > 75) & (df3['subject'] == 'math' & df3['marks'] > 85) ):
    res = 'pass'
  elif ((df3['subject'] == 'viva' & df3['marks'] > 50 ) & (df3['subject'] == 'science' & df3['marks'] > 45) & (df3['subject'] == 'math' & df3['marks'] > 55)) :
    res = 'reattempt'
  else:
    res = 'fail'
  return res


testdata = open('/c:/TestData.csv')
testdataReader = csv.reader(testdata)
testdatalist  = list(testdataReader)
  
for row in testdatalist:
   j = "{'id':" + row[0] + ",'student_name':" + row[1] + ",'class':'" + row[2] + "'}"
   j = j.replace("'",'"')
   j = ast.literal_eval(j)
   response = requests.post(url, json=j)
   df2 = df2.append(response.json(), ignore_index=True)

df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df3['result'] = df3.apply(lambda row : passfail_logic(row ), axis = 1)
df3.to_csv('C:/StudentResult.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: `df3['c']` is a column of the dataframe.  It contains many values.  The comparison `df3['c'] == 'Science'` is nonsense.  It makes no sense to ask "Is this dataframe column equal to this string?"  Maybe some values in the column are equal to that string, and maybe others aren't.  It makes no sense to compare the column _as a whole_ to a string.

Comment: I have edited my original post for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: here's what's wrong after you updated:

```py
def passfail_logic(row):
  if ((df3['subject'] == 'viva' & df3['marks'] ...
```

`df3` should be `row`, the `&` should be `and` I don't think you want the bitwise operator here. I think this is why you keep seeing something about converting to string, `'viva' & df3['marks']` this gets priority in the evaluation and it doesn't know how to compare string (`'viva'`) to the series (`df3['marks']`). You could wrap these in parenthesis like `(df3['subject]=='viva') & (df3['marks']=='...')` but you can also just change to `and`

---

What `df3[df3['c'] == 'Science']` is doing is basically filtering your dataframe to any rows where column 'c' is 'Science'. So what you end up with is something like if([filtered dataframe]) and it doesn't know how to check the truthfulness of that statement.

It's hard for me to give more information on what to do though because I don't know what you're trying to do with the 'Science' data.

If you just want to grab the filtered data then you could do something like

```py
filtered_df = df3[df3['c'] == 'Science']
```

if you wanted to apply a function where that column is science you could do something like

```py
def some_function(value):
  if value == 'Science':
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

df3['science'] = df3['c'].apply(some_function)
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do something similar , but the code errors at the if statement. Is there a way to convert the series to string type for comparison?

Comment: @Passive_coder I just caught another error, change the &s

Comment: Thank you , that was quick. That did resolve that issue. I now have another error for 'marks' column. 'u'occurred at index 10'' - Do you see why it is erring for this? The datatype is int64, should I try to change the type for this?

Comment: That looks like only a partial error message. You could try to enforce a type on the column (`.apply(int)` before the row-based apply) and see what happens. Hard to know without seeing the data, could be there is missing data there like a null, so converting to int may not work and you need to fill the nulls in that column with 0, look up the `fillna` method

Comment: I passed wrong values to the column. The code is working now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem glad it is working

Answer (score 0):

Count if any rows were found to evaluate truthiness.

```py
if df3[df3['c'] == 'Science'].shape[0]:
    ...
```

Comment: Rows are there for that value.